# Kill All Child Processes But Not The Parent Processes Upon Timeout Error

Tags: python, process, multiprocessing, psutil

```
while True:
    pid = os.getpid()
    try:
        pool = mp.Pool(processes=1, maxtasksperchild=1)
        result = pool.apply_async(my_func, args=())
        result.get(timeout=60)
        pool.close()
    except multiprocessing.context.TimeoutError:
        traceback.print_exc()
        kill_proc_tree(pid)

def kill_proc_tree(pid):
    parent = psutil.Process(pid)
    children = parent.children(recursive=True)
    for child in children:
        child.kill()
```

I am using the multiprocessing library and am trying to spawn a new process everytime `my_func` finishes running, throws an exception, or has ran longer than 60 seconds (`result.get(timeout=60)` should throw an exception). Since I want to keep the while loop running but also avoid having zombie processes, I need to be able to keep the parent process running but at the same time, kill all child processes if an exception is thrown in the parent process or the child process, or the child process finishes before spawning a new process.The `kill_proc_tree` function that I found online was supposed to tackle the issue which it seemed to do at first (my_func opens a new window when a process begins and closes the window when the process supposedly ends), but then I realized that in my Task Manager, the Python Script is still taking up my memory and after enough `multiprocessing.context.TimeoutError` errors (they are thrown by the parent process), my memory becomes full.

So what I should I do to solve this problem? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution should be as simple as calling method `terminate` on the pool for all exceptions and not just for a `TimeoutError` since `result.get(timeout=60)` can throw an arbitrary exception if your `my_func` completes before the 60 seconds with an exception.

Note that according to the documentation the `terminate` method "stops the worker processes immediately without completing outstanding work" and will be implicitly called when the context handler for the pool is exited as in the following example:

```py
import multiprocessing

while True:
    try:
        with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=1, maxtasksperchild=1) as pool:
            result = pool.apply_async(my_func, args=())
            result.get(timeout=60)
    except Exception:
        pass
```

Specifying the *maxtasksperchild=1* parameter to the `Pool` constructor seems somewhat superfluous since you are never submitting more than one task to the pool anyway.